# div collapses when there is text in it

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with collapsing div.
When I add some amount of text it collapses from parent div.
Here is the HTML code

```css
    .container {
      width:80%;
      height:50%;
      background-color:#eee;
      padding: 30px
    }

    html,body {
      height:100%;
    }

    .chart {
      background: red;
      width: 30px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
       <div class="chart" style="height: 10%"></div>
       <div class="chart" style="height: 20%"></div>
       <div class="chart" style="height: 70%">test</div>
       <div class="chart" style="height: 100%"></div>
    </div>
```

And demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5YukJ/485/

Comment: Do you want the text at the top of the bar or the bottom? If at the top, you can use vertical-align: bottom.

Comment: where do you want the text to be displayed? Do you even want the text to be displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: bottom;`

```
.chart {
    background: red;
    width: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably realize that in your example the position of the columns relies on the tallest column,
in your case it is the last one,

if I had to draw some columns in a situation like this I'd go for flex:

```css
.container {
      width:80%;
      height:50%;
      background-color:#eee;
      padding: 30px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-end;
    }

    html,body {
      height:100%;
    }

    .chart {
      background: red;
      flex: 0 0 30px;
      margin-right: 10px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
       <div class="chart" style="height: 10%"></div>
       <div class="chart" style="height: 20%"></div>
       <div class="chart" style="height: 70%">test</div>
       <div class="chart" style="height: 100%"></div>
    </div>
```

that said check browser support.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is using `vertical-align` as @FelixAJ said. The problem mainly is due to the overflow that causes the inner text. Using `vertical-align` you override this default behaviour. Additionaly, I recommend you using a `min-width` instead `width` to avoid the overflow. With this approach the width of the bar will grow depending of the inner text.